# Discord bot not wroking

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I am currently learning how to make a **discord bot using python**. But I am stuck at the beginning. My bot is **not responding**.

It is NOT showing an error. Also in the discord server the bot is showing online.

But when I run `guild.member_count` it shows the correct number of members. But when I try to get the information of the members by `guild.members`, it just shows my bot in the list.

Moreover If I try to send message by `await member.create_dm()` in `on_member_join()`, it don't send any message.

Also I gave the bot **administrator** permission to see if its some problem with permissions but still the same.

Below is my code :

```
import discord

TOKEN = <MyToken> # I have replaced this with my actual token in the actual code

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = discord.utils.get(client.guilds, name=GUILD)
    print(
        f"{client.user} is connected to Discord!\n"
        f"Connected to {guild.name} (id: {guild.id}, members-count: {guild.member_count})"
        )
    members = '\n - '.join([member.name for member in guild.members])
    print(f'Guild Members:\n - {members}')


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(
        f"Hello {member.name}, Welcome to the test discord server!"
    )
    print(f"Welcomed {member.name}.\n")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it just shows my bot in the list.

See this page on [Gateway Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)

> it don't send any message

Try just using

```
await member.send(...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I was trying to fix this since a couple of days. I wasn't able to find anything on google either. Again thanks a lot.